# Twilio in Turborepo shared library throwing error

Tags: typescript, next.js, twilio

I'm in process of converting a Next.js application into a monorepo using Turborepo. Part of the project has been extracting some shared libraries into a package, with a `plaid` connection, `prismic` connection, and a `twilio` connection.

My monorepo is structured this way:

```
├── apps
│   ├── next-app
│   └── other-next-app
└── packages
    └── library
        ├── twilio.ts
        ├── index.ts
        └── package.json
```

[More details about Turborepo.](https://turborepo.org)

In my package.json for the library, I include `twilio`:

**packages/library/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@vero/lib",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "source": "./src/index.ts",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "license": "MIT",
  "files": [
    "dist/**"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "VeroSkills",
    "email": "contact@veroskills.com"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "tsc -w",
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "TIMING=1 eslint src/**/*.ts* --fix",
    "clean": "rm -rf .turbo && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf dist"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prismicio/client": "^6.5.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.31.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@vero/prisma": "*",
    "@vero/tsconfig": "*",
    "eslint-config-vero": "*",
    "next-auth": "^4.3.4",
    "plaid": "^10.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-plaid-link": "^3.3.2",
    "twilio": "^3.77.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

And I create the client this way:

**twilio.ts**

```
import twilioClient from 'twilio';

export const twilio = twilioClient(
  process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
);
```

From there, I export this client from my `index.ts` in the root:

**index.ts**

```
export { twilio } from './twilio';
```

And I install the shared package in my apps:

```
"@vero/library": "*"
```

I'm using this `twilio` config in a couple of API routes in a Next.js application within the monorepo:

**notify.ts**

```
import { getSession, twilio } from '@vero/lib';
import { prisma } from '@vero/prisma';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    res.status(405).json({ status: 'Method not allowed...' });
  } else {
    const session = await getSession({ req });

    if (!session) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: 'User is not signed in...',
        success: false,
      });
    }

    try {
      const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
      const availableTutors = await prisma.tutors.findMany({
        where: {
          currentlyOnline: true,
          acceptPhoneNotifications: true,
          languages: {
            contains: body.language,
          },
        },
        select: {
          notificationPhoneNumber: true,
          user: true,
        },
      });

      const tutors = availableTutors.map((tutor) => {
        return {
          number: tutor.notificationPhoneNumber,
          user: tutor.user,
        };
      });

      Promise.all(
        tutors.map((tutor) => {
          return twilio.messages.create({
            to: tutor.number,
            from: process.env.TWILIO_MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID,
            body: `Hi ${
              tutor.user.name?.split(' ')[0]
            }, a VeroSkills student has requested assistance in ${body.language.toUpperCase()}. To accept the call visit ${
              process.env.ROOT_URL
            }/meeting/${body.meetingName}`,
          });
        })
      );

      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Error writing to the database...',
        success: false,
        error: error,
      });
    }
  }
};

export default handler;
```

However, when I run the applications that use my `twilio` config, I'm receiving this error in the browser:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'net'

Import trace for requested module:
../../node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js
../../node_modules/twilio/lib/base/RequestClient.js
../../node_modules/twilio/lib/index.js
../../packages/lib/dist/twilio.js
../../packages/lib/dist/index.js
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Is it possible that you are importing the Twilio client into front-end code? The library is only designed to work in a Node.js environment, so would throw errors like this when trying to use it in a browser environment.

Comment: No, this API route is it. Could it possibly be my something about tsconfig and module resolution? Or the compilation of the package?

Comment: I think it might be something to do with the composition and compilation of the packages. Can you describe your monorepo structure in a bit more depth? Like, where does the Next app live, where is this connector app, and how do they fit together? Thanks!

Comment: @philnash updated my question; let me know if that's enough detail.

Comment: This might be silly, but you have `twilio` in the `devDependencies` of your library package, but I would have thought it would need to be in `dependencies` since you intend to use it at runtime. Does moving it there help?

Comment: I gave that a try already, but I'm in process of rewriting my packages for organizational purposes; I'll give that another try.

Comment: Are you certain you're not importing `@vero/lib` anywhere else in the Next.js apps?

Comment: I'm importing `@vero/lib` other places, yes, but not the `twilio` client.

Comment: @JesseWinton were you able to get this figured out?

Comment: @BlakePetersen I ended up not needing to utilize Twilio, so I didn't spend much more time on it. Are you having similar issues?